# SQL compare attributes to another row's attribute in the same table

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table of people with their names and Dates of Birth.
How can I select all people's names who have greater DofB than another person while only knowing that persons name and not DofB?

Comment: Provide sample data and output

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @Kobi I'm not sure about the syntax that's why I'm asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some options, but I like a JOIN here.

Assuming you have a unique name field (using a unique row identifier like id is probably better):

```
SELECT p.name
  FROM person p
  JOIN person po
    ON po.name = :name_that_you_know
 WHERE p.dob > po.dob
```

This cross JOINs every person row with the row of the person that you named.
The results are filtered by the date of birth comparison.

Alternatively you can perform the filter in the JOIN condition:

```
SELECT p.name
  FROM person p
  JOIN person po
    ON po.name = :name_that_you_know
   AND po.dob < p.dob
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple mysql query like

`SELECT a.name, b.dob FROM table a INNER JOIN table b ON b.name = 'john' AND a.dob > b.dob`

Something like that

Comment: I do not know the date of birth, I only know the name of the person.

Answer (score 1):

This will find all people with a DOB greater (or younger) than the a person you are not sure of their DOB, but know their name:

```
SELECT name
FROM yourTable
WHERE DOB > (SELECT DOB FROM yourTable WHERE name = 'nameyouknow');
```